# ASP.NET - Where click on ImageButton, btn stay block state

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, imagebutton

My solution is  **C# Class Library** and  I want to add `_spFormOnSubmitCalled = false;`
`_spSuppressFormOnSubmitWrapper = true;`, because my button stay block after click.

This is my code, where I add this below properties.

**below is my code where I add this:**

```
ImageButton btnAddHelp = new ImageButton();
btnAddHelp.AlternateText = "HELP ME?";
btnAddHelp.OnClientClick = "target='blank'";
btnAddHelp.TabIndex = 2;
btnAddHelp.PostBackUrl = "http://sf-spsdev02/TestSite/Shared%20Documents/UserGiude-WayBill%20System.pdf";
btnAddHelp.ImageUrl = "~/_layouts/images/hhelp.GIF
```

How to do this with HyperLink controll :

**This is my code :**

```
HyperLink btnEditHelp = new HyperLink();
btnEditHelp.Text = "";
btnEditHelp.ID = "dasdasdsa";
btnEditHelp.ToolTip = "HELP ME?";
btnEditHelp.ImageUrl = "~/_layouts/images/hhelp.GIF";
btnEditHelp.Target = "_blank";
//btnEditHelp. = "_spFormOnSubmitCalled = false; _spSuppressFormOnSubmitWrapper = true; target='blank;";
btnEditHelp.NavigateUrl = "http://sf-spsdev02/TestSite/Shared%20Documents/UserGiude-WayBill%20System.pdf";
```

Gives me following error:

> An error has occurred because a control with id 'ctl00$m$WayBillModule1$ctl01' could not be located or a different control is assigned to the same ID after postback. If the ID is not assigned, explicitly set the ID property of controls that raise postback events to avoid this error.

Thank you previously.. :)

Comment: Theres no simple way of having it disable after the first click.  You could store that it's been clicked in a session variable and on page load set the enabled property to false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is solve my problem :))**

```
    HyperLink btnEditHelp = new HyperLink();
    btnEditHelp.Text = "";
    btnEditHelp.ID = "link";
    btnEditHelp.ToolTip = "Helppp?";
    btnEditHelp.ImageUrl = "~/_layouts/images/hhelp.GIF";
    btnEditHelp.Target = "_blank";
    btnEditHelp.NavigateUrl = "http://sf-spsdev02/TestSite/Shared%20Documents/UserGiude-WayBill%20System.pdf";
```